# Deluge proxy settings greyed out

Tags: deluge

Why are my Deluge v1.3.15 proxy settings greyed out? How can I set them?

[image]

Comment: Same for me with v1.3.15. I don't know what causes that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is now only a single proxy setting that applies to all types of traffic.**

This is by design and as a result of changes in the underlying libtorrent library. In Deluge 1.3 for simplicity, the other types are greyed-out to prevent any bugs.

Reference: [1.3.15 Release Notes](https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/ReleaseNotes/1.3.15)